# Get weeks from two dates jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get number of weeks from two dates in jQuery 1.0?

I have tried this but no luck:

```
 //start and end date is in format '10-0ct-2015'

 var end = $("span[id$=spEstDeliveryDate] input[type=text]").val();
 var start = $("span[id$=spPODeliveryDate] input[type=text]").val();

 var f = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd-M-yy", end);
 var date1 = new Date(f);
date1 = (date1.getDate() + '/' + (date1.getMonth() + 1 ) + '/' +       date1.getFullYear());

f = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd-M-yy", start);
var date2 = new Date(f);
date2 = (date2.getDate() + '/' + (date2.getMonth() + 1)  + '/' + date2.getFullYear());

var totalWeeks = Math.floor((date1 - date2 + 1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 7);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You convert the dates to strings before trying to do the math on them. Leave them as `Date` objects:

```
var f = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd-M-yy", end);
var date1 = new Date(f);

f = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd-M-yy", start);
var date2 = new Date(f);

var totalWeeks = Math.floor((date1 - date2) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 7);
```